# How to remove sensitive information from issue history on GitHub

Tags: github, github-issues

I am using a public GitHub repository to collaborate on a project. Because I am an idiot, I created an issue with some sensitive information that I can't share.

Because I need the overall issue information, and the sensitive information could be withdrawn with no meaningful effects, is there a way to remove it from the issue without the necessity to [delete](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/deleting-an-issue) it?

Most of the answers I've found talk about removing information from files and their commits, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423687/deleting-sensitive-data-after-push).

Answer (score 11):

1. Click on *edited* in the top bar of the edited issue
2. Click on the revision you want to remove in the popup menu
3. Click on *Options*
4. Click on *Delete revision from history*

Note

> The most recent revision cannot be deleted.
> Need to delete sensitive information? Go to the specific edit where the information was added.

To delete the most recent revision, make another new revision. Then the previously most recent revision can be deleted.

[image: screenshot issue comment with popup menu]

[image: screenshot revision options]

There will still be an entry in the list of all revisions, but it's not clickable anymore and the content is not available.

See also the GitHub documentation:
https://docs.github.com/en/communities/moderating-comments-and-conversations/tracking-changes-in-a-comment#deleting-sensitive-information-from-a-comments-history

Comment: Doesn't work. It is still visible.

Comment: It seems to work (duly appreciated), because the sensitive data becomes inaccessible via the web interface, but the revision history still contains the timestamp of your removed edit (marked as deleted), so it is possible that the contents with  the sensitive data are still left in the database, not just their timestamp.

Comment: I think Github treats Issue history just like comment history, <https://docs.github.com/en/communities/moderating-comments-and-conversations/tracking-changes-in-a-comment#deleting-sensitive-information-from-a-comments-history>